# What's the meaning of "straight baller" in this sentence? Is "baller" a solid word in English?

Tags: word-meaning

I came across this sentence:

[>She's just like a straight baller, she's amazing and doesn't take any crap from anybody.](http://www.seattlepi.com/local/crime/article/Watch-Everett-nanny-nabs-potential-package-12404505.php)

What's the meaning of "straight baller" in this sentence? Is "baller" a solid word in English?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this comes for basketball talk. A "baller" is someone that plays basketball, and a "straight baller" is a term used to describe people who play basketball very well. Since it is being used in a context outside of basketball, it's meaning is basically that the person in question is very good at what they do.